# Access adapter from within onCheckedChanged()

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've created an adapter for ViewPager. When I create it, I also have to dynamically create radio buttons on the layouts. However, by clicking one of the radio buttons, i need to notifyDataSetChanged of the adapter it's inside. How do I access that adapter? For example, if I wanted to do this:

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
        boolean isChecked) {

              viewPagerLength++;
             // need to call notifyDataSetChanged();     
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting radioButton like so:

final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);

and then you can access radioButton from within.